# Known algorithms: subgraph with highest/lowest diameter?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Let be $G=(V,E)$ a directed graph without self loops, where each node has an out-degree of at least $k$.

We want to find a $E'\subset E$, so that $G'=(V,E')$ has the following properties:

- Almost all nodes in $G'$ have an out-degree of: $l \le k$
- $G'$ has the highest possible diameter

The *almost all nodes* part is to relax a bit the problem.

e.g. if $G'$ is a DAG, the last $l$ nodes can't have an out-degree of $l$. But a DAG, or a linear graph, can have a high diameter.

There is also the similar problem, where we want to find $G'$ with the lowest possible diameter.

---

I have some ideas on how to solve these problems, without finding the optimal solution. In particular the variant *max diameter* seems doable.

However I'd like to know if there is some literature about these (or similar, or simpler) problems. And if there are algorithms to find optimal or approximated solutions.
I couldn't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: "Hamiltonian Cycle in a directed graph" is a special case of the (unrelaxed max-diameter) form of the problem: simply set $l=1$.  As this is NP-hard, so is your problem.  If your relaxation allows 2 outdegree-0 vertices, the problem (with $l=1$ again) is now to look for a Hamiltonian Path (also NP-hard).

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yeah, but this doesn't implies that even the $l>1$ version is NP-hard...

(to look for a Hamiltonian Path with $l=1$, should enough a single node with $outdegree=0$)

Comment: It's still NP-hard for any given $l > 1$: Reduce from the same problem (HC in a digraph), but construct the input instance for your problem differently: instead of just using the same graph $G$, add a complete directed graph on $l$ vertices $u_1, \dots, u_l$ to it, and add $n(l-1)$ edges from every $v \in V$ to the first $l-1$ of these new vertices (i.e., add the edge $(v_i, u_j)$ for all $1 \le i \le n$ and $1 \le j \le l-1$).  There's a subgraph $H$ of this graph that (a) has every vertex of outdegree $l$ and (b) contains a shortest path of length $n-1$ iff there is a HC in $G$.

Comment: Also I didn't understand the part of your comment in parentheses...